# Django Python rest framework, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in chrome, works in firefox

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have researched and read quite a few Stackoverflow posts on the same issue. None have resolved my issue.

My problem is that I am getting the "...No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource..." error in my console.

I am using:

Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133
Firefox Version 52.0.2

Python 2.7
Django 1.11a1

AngularJS

I am using MAMP to serve my front-end Angular stuff, and the django server for the backend stuff.

In my django settings I have included the cors middleware and tried both the whitelist approach and just setting all to true:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

On google chrome I still get this error:

> localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load {my endpoint url}. Redirect
>   from {my endpoint url} to {my endpoint url with a } has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource. Origin {requesting url} is therefore not
>   allowed access.

It works appropriately on Firefox, and I can't figure out why it won't work for google chrome. I haven't tried any other types of browsers. Any help will be very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I am having this problem too -- it works in FF but not Chrome.  I have the corsheaders in my INSTALLED_APPS and the two lines mentioned in the MIDDLEWARE, and I've got CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST set to a list with 'http://localhost:8080' as the first item.  I've also tried adding the following headers to the JSONResponse: 
def set_cors_headers(rsp: JSONResponse, method: str)->JSONResponse:
    rsp.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    rsp.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method)
    rsp.__setitem__("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
    return rsp

Answer (score 98):

Install the cors-headers package with

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Adds to your installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

Add on your MIDDLEWARE 
**remember to add as being the first in the list**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Before installed apps put this configuration for anyone to access

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
```

Or create a list of hits

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://google.com',
    'http://hostname.example.com',
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:9000'
]
```

Comment: Did not work for me for `django 2.1.4` and `django-cors-headers 2.4.0` which are both the latest versions at the time of writing.

Comment: the question clearly states that he had installed cors-headers already and that the problem lies between Chrome and FF

Comment: Small correction, the last part should be with `[` instead of `(`.

Comment: You must add "http://" for example as the error you'll give says: Origin 'localhost:3000' in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST is missing  scheme or netloc

Comment: Thank you. It's the simplest tutorial I have ever found.

Comment: as mentioned by @normic this is clearly not the proper answer to the question.

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 60):

Check your request URL first. I had this problem when while using vue-resource. In my case, the error was a missing '/' at the end of url.

Comment: Had the same issue and this was the fix for me. See also this post from '15(!) for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33377351/5745325

Comment: This is the solution. Should be accepted as answer.

Comment: This is the solution for me at least in Angular 2+

Comment: For Angular in my case, the URL had two slashes //. In that case, shouldn't it be the 404?

Comment: It was really very very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: SAved my day using axios with vue

Comment: same here, would not have caught this for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure use `127.0.0.1` NOT `localhost` because when using `localhost` browser may look up an IPv6 address...
or set up `localhost` to explicitly to `127.0.0.1` at `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 3):

In my case,
First of all make sure if you apply all [these](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) settings. then if you use axios or same things in frontend make sure that you define `METHOD` in options.

‌‌
‌
‌ ‌
‌
‌
`python -m pip install django-cors-headers`

django

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
```

js

```
const options = {
        url: "http://localhost:8000/blog/v1/",
        // buttom sections 
        method: "GET", 
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
          },
        // top section
        
    };
    axios(options)
        .then(
            response => {
                return response.data
            }
        )
```

## ***UPDATE***

add the following code to settings.py

```
# <myproject/setting.py>
from .DEFAULT import DEFAULT_HEADERS

...
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = DEFAULT_HEADERS
```

and in DEFAULTS.py

```
# <myproject/DEFAULTS.py>
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers


DEFAULT_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
    "WWW-Authenticate",
    "Authorization",
    "Proxy-Authenticate",
    "Proxy-Authorization",
    "Age",
    "Cache-Control",
    "Clear-Site-Data",
    "Expires",
    "Pragma",
    "Warning",
    "Accept-CH",
    "Accept-CH-Lifetime",
    "Sec-CH-UA",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Arch",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Bitness",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Mobile",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Model",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Platform",
    "Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version",
    "Content-DPR",
    "Device-Memory",
    "DPR",
    "Viewport-Width",
    "Width",
    "Downlink",
    "ECT",
    "RTT",
    "Save-Data",
    "Last-Modified",
    "ETag",
    "If-Match",
    "If-None-Match",
    "If-Modified-Since",
    "If-Unmodified-Since",
    "Vary",
    "Connection",
    "Keep-Alive",
    "Accept",
    "Accept-Encoding",
    "Accept-Language",
    "Expect",
    "Max-Forwards",
    "Cookie",
    "Set-Cookie",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age",
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "Origin",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin",
    "Content-Disposition",
    "Content-Length",
    "Content-Type",
    "Content-Encoding",
    "Content-Language",
    "Content-Location",
    "Forwarded",
    "X-Forwarded-For",
    "X-Forwarded-Host",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto",
    "Via",
    "Location",
    "From",
    "Host",
    "Referer",
    "Referrer-Policy",
    "User-Agent",
    "Allow",
    "Server",
    "Accept-Ranges",
    "Range",
    "If-Range",
    "Content-Range",
    "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy",
    "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
    "Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy",
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only",
    "Expect-CT",
    "Feature-Policy",
    "Origin-Isolation",
    "Strict-Transport-Security",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
    "X-Content-Type-Options",
    "X-Download-Options",
    "X-Frame-Options",
    "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies",
    "X-Powered-By",
    "X-XSS-Protection",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
    "Sec-Fetch-User",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
    "Service-Worker-Navigation-Preload",
    "Last-Event-ID",
    "NEL",
    "Ping-From",
    "Ping-To",
    "Report-To",
    "Transfer-Encoding",
    "TE",
    "Trailer",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Key",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol",
    "Sec-WebSocket-Version",
    "Accept-Push-Policy",
    "Accept-Signature",
    "Alt-Svc",
    "Date",
    "Early-Data",
    "Large-Allocation",
    "Link",
    "Push-Policy",
    "Retry-After",
    "Signature",
    "Signed-Headers",
    "Server-Timing",
    "Service-Worker-Allowed",
    "SourceMap",
    "Upgrade",
    "X-DNS-Prefetch-Control",
    "X-Firefox-Spdy",
    "X-Pingback",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "X-Robots-Tag",
    "X-UA-Compatible",
    "ContentType",
    "Content-type",
    "content-type",
    "contenttype",
    "contentType",


    "accept",
    "authorization",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",

    "accept-encoding",

    "Contentype",
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to take a look at how you are calling your middlewares. If they are not in the correct sequence they might throw this error. It seems like your `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'` needs to be pushed below the `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'`.
Also, it looks like you might have to add 
`CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` in your code as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm still having the same issue. An update though: I have two endpoints that I am trying to hit, and in my views.py, serializers.py, and urls.py they are created exactly the same, the only difference really is the models. The 2nd of my two endpoints is working properly in chrome, but the first is still throwing the cors headers error described above. Both work as intended in firefox.

Comment: This is kind of peculiar. Are we sure that all the packages have been installed properly or some dependency that has been missed. Ideally you adding 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' should have worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was fighting with this CORS issue when making a GET call from my Angular-app.
After 1-2 hours looking at this error `from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

It just turned out that my URL was invalid. **I was missing a single `/`** from the end of the URL. I actually tried every answer...

See also: [Django CORS API from AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333323/django-cors-api-from-angularjs)

edit: After looking at the server log I can see that HTTP 301 was returned on every failed call. [Django returning HTTP 301?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579846/django-returning-http-301)

edit2: might also be helpful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

Answer (score 0):

the reason that is chrome browse; you can install CORS Toggle app in chrome or deploy your web code to nginx or apache then using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I'm not seeing this solution, which worked for me, anywhere.  So hoping this can be helpful for someone.

Cross-origin requests in this context are only possible if the partner site's server allows it through their response headers.

I got this to work in Django **without any CORS middleware** by setting the following headers on the response:

```
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "requesting_site.com"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET"
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "requesting_site.com"
```

Most answers on StackOverflow seem to mention the first one, **but not the second two**.  I've just confirmed they are all required.  You'll want to modify as needed for your framework or request method (GET, POST, OPTION).

p.s. You can try `"*"` instead of `"requesting_site.com"` for initial development just to get it working, but it would be a security hole to allow *every* site access.  Once working, you can restrict it for your requesting site only to make sure you don't have any formatting typos.

Comment: Actually you are solution worked for me with reverse. I have removed you mentioned code in frontend, the application worked well.

Comment: @Shakthifuture Glad it worked for you.  If so, consider an upvote to give the answer more weight.  That's how this works.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> In settings.py

```
 MIDDLEWARE = [
         #...
             'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
             'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
         ]
 INSTALLED_APPS = [

            'corsheaders',
             #...
            ]
# Set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL is True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # this allows all domains

#Or to allow specific domains 

 CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'http://example.com',
'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
'http://localhost:8000',
)
```

> Along with your configurations, you should add headers in frontend call:

```
 var get_request = $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 "headers": {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
  },
 url: 'http://example.com',
 });
```

> If it is not solved, You should enable the core in requesting server(http://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Could not make it work after trying everything mentioned here. In fact, everything mentioned in the django-cors-headers documentation was already there in my settings.py.

After a lot of digging in, I found out the culprit was the "MIDDLEWARE" definition itself in settings.py. According to my version of django (which is 1.7) it needs to be "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES" and not "MIDDLEWARE". You can find this out when you look at the django documentation for middlewares which can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/ (don't forget to choose your version of django from right bottom corner). When this change was done, my preflights started returning the needed response headers.

Still scratching my head thinking how simple was the solution (when found out) for an issue which took hours away from me :(

Comment: The answer is presupposed on the idea that they are using an outdated version of Django, which is incorrect. It is probably pertinent to ask the original poster which version of Django they are using and go from there.

Comment: @Ananth admit, the issue cost me a fair amount of time. This is just another dimension that people can look into. Thought of posting it here because there can be people like me digging in without even thinking of this dimension

Comment: Which is exactly why it should be a comment on the question and not an answer. If the poster does use an outdated Django, then you would post this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

#### VERY IMPORTANT SETTINGS THAT MAKES CORS ERROR WORK

After adding all the above , please please make sure to add this,

For me this worked, I have added all the above, and it did not work,

Added the following line in settings.py, it worked, ( In addition to all the code that's put in settings.py )

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = "*"

Comment: @TD1  This is not 
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # this allows all domains, This is to allow all headers only.

Answer (score -3):

You can install [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) app and in the settings.py you should put `'corsheaders'`
 in the INSTALLED_APPS and

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

in the starting of the MIDDLEWARE of the settings

The README of the Github link explains the details

Comment: Since i see that you have Middleware settings.I assume you have already installed the corsheaders. Just make sure 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', are in the top of the MiddleWare settings

Comment: Not what the official documentation says...django's `SecurityMiddleware` and `SessionMiddleware` should always be on top for security reasons...

Answer (score -3):

see if your url is correct.
For me it works by doing following things:

1. install django cors headers package
   `# django-cors-headers`
2. Add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` in settings.py
3. Add this two line in start at MIDDLEWARE tag
   `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware`
   `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware`
4. add below line into INSTALLED_APPS
   `corsheader`
5. And added back slash at the end of url like 
   `http://127.0.0.1:8000/getcust/`