# Html: filter the second selector based on the first selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZzOi.png)

As shown in picture above, I need to update the choices of second selector(Product) based on the selection made in the first selector(Region).

Below is the JQuery code I used to do the job, with the help of Json file(see below the script):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#first-choice").change(function() {

    var $dropdown = $(this);

    $.getJSON("mysite/App/templates/data.json", function(data) {
        alert("Success");

        var key = $dropdown.val();
        var vals = [];

        switch(key) {
            case 'APAC':
                vals = data.APAW.split(",");
                break;
            case 'MEA':
                vals = data.ME.split(",");
                break;
            case 'base':
                vals = ['Please choose from above'];
        }

        var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
        $secondChoice.empty();
        $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
            $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
        });
    });
});
};
    </script>
```

Json file content: { "ER": "12", "FE": "few, SL" }

Here is the HTML file related to the selectors:

```
<h1>Region</h1>
<select id="first-choice">
  <option value="base">Please Select</option>
  <option value="EE">E</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<br>

<h1>Product</h1>
<select id="second-choice">
  <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: @CodeThing The problem is that the second selector doesn't update based on the selection of first selector.

Comment: Is there any error showing in the console? Seems like you did not close `$(document).ready(function(){` properly

Comment: @CodeThing No, I am just testing it in the Chrome, where can I see the error?

Comment: On the chrome just right click and click 'Inspect' or hit F12. You will see a small window at the bottom. Click on console tab and refresh your page

Comment: @CodeThing Yes, there is a warning: "Failed to load file:///D:/Programming/productDeliveryAutomation/mysite/App/templates/data.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Comment: It means your json file is not accessible with getJSON request. You should access this using your project url. Is your website on local or is it live?

Comment: @CodeThing Still on my local PC, just for testing at the moment. It is in the same folder with the HTML file. How can I fix this?  Thx

Comment: You should call this json file with url. Try using your project url and then path upto that json file. Something like `https://localhost/yourwebsite/data.json`

Comment: @CodeThing But is there a way to test it locally? I mean just the HTML file without in a local server.

Comment: @CodeThing Tried test it on localhost, but there is still a error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/templates/data.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Seems do not have access to that file

Comment: If you don't have the local server setup, then you can just use the file name `$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {`

Comment: @CodeThing Thx a lot, it worked without running the server. However, when I test it on the server, it says" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", and the code I am using now is "$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {"

Comment: yes, thats right it on server you will need to access that with website url. I am adding this in answer, please accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the file name in getJson

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
```

Comment: "$.getJSON("http://http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.json", function(data) {". This is not working. BTW, the data.json file is located in the same folder with home.html.

Comment: `website` folder is your root of your website? D:/Programming/productDeliveryAutomation/mysite/App/templates/data.json
Is that right?

Comment: "mysite" is the root folder of my website.

Comment: What is website url that you are using?

Comment: Try adding your json file on root and call this `http://localhost:8000/data.json`

Comment: "Failed to load http://localhost:8000/data.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404." Still...

Comment: Change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the getJSON call.

Comment: It should work. if you hit that url in the browser and you are getting the json then it should work in this case. What framework are you using for your website?

Comment: I dont know much about django framework and this looks like framework setting issue. Please check this issue you get any help from there.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357687/django-python-rest-framework-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: Finally sovled by putting the json file into the static folder where these source files should locate.